# To extend the last day of work due to manager asking me to

Tags: resignation

I work through a temp staffing for ABC company,after 8 months of working there I decided to quit my job due to personal reasons which is acceptable. When I sent my resignation letter with a notice period I came to know that I need to give 2 weeks notice. Due to circumstances they have to consider 1 week notice. But my manager called me to her desk and ask if I could extend my last day and asked me to email the staffing company requesting to extend the last day.

When I emailed the staffing company to extend the last day of work I got a reply
"Are you sure? I will go back to them to see if they can support" I have no idea what does this mean. I have a doubt that my manager is playing dual roles.

How do I reply to them that my manager requested me to extend.

How do I let the staffing company know that my manager asked me to do so?

Comment: Have you made it clear to your staffing company that the last day of work should be extended due to a request from your Manager?  Based on your response above, maybe they think that you're requesting to extend the last day and they need to check with the Manager to see whether they would support that.  The reality is that there's nothing to support since your Manager is the one that's requested the change.

Answer (score 10):

> "Are you sure? I will go back to them to see if they can support"

Clearly your staffing company thought that it is you who is requesting the extension and not the manager. You just have to clearly word it out something like

> My manager here has asked me to extend my last day. I want to help them out if I can. Can we do it?

Comment: Agreed, the wording of this makes it sound like they think this is you changing your mind about the day you want to finish, when in reality you are offering to help the company out. I can't see why the company would refuse to support a request from their own manager, but either way if you've made the request with PagMax's clarification, then you've done all you can.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how this is a problem.  At all.  You've got two parties, and you're simply a medium of communication between the two.  Just relay their messages diligently, keeping both sides apprised of the situation.  Either all three parties are okay with it (you, the company, the temp agency) and you work the extra hours, or someone has a problem with it and you don't.

Comment: The key takeaway is the OP is responsible for zero decision here. The resignation is already handed in. The employer and the temp agency needs to work things out.